# Оставить нули при делении на ноль, вместо inf в Python через NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x

Если дан массив, в котором есть нули, и нужно получить обратную величину, но, при этом, если ошибка деления на ноль или inf в случае использования Numpy - необходимо в новом массиве заменить inf на ноль.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-1, 0, 1])
b = 1/a
print(b)
```

Ответом будет [-1. inf  1.].
А нужно [-1. 0 1.], как получить?
Пробовал через цикл, но никак не вышло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [numpy.divide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html):

```py
b = np.divide(1, a, where=a!=0)
```

`a != 0` вернёт массив `[True, False, True]`, поэтому 0 будет игнорироваться

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать замену `inf` на 0 через:

```
b[np.isinf(b)] = 0
```

[Пример:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34257464/5909792)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-1, 0, 1])
b = 1 / a
print(b)
# [-1. inf  1.]

b[np.isinf(b)] = 0
print(b)
# [-1.  0.  1.]
```

Comment: @Overd, я думаю, ответ **timur** больше подходит для решения вашей проблеме

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте данный способ:

```
import numpy as np
b = []
a = np.array([-1, 0, 1])
for i in a:
    if  i != 0:
        b.append(int(1/i))
    else:
        b.append(0)
print(b)
```